# Startup jackrabbit standalone with postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jackrabbit

I need to start jackrabbit with postgresql persistence support enabled. I changed the repository.xml configuration file adding the right properties to connect db but I'm not able to set the class path and, for that reason, this exception is raised:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I use:

```
java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.2.10.jar -c ./repository.xml -p 8081 -d
```

how can I tell java where is the jdbc postgres jar file? with -jar any class path definition is ignored.

thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to place the PostgreSQL JDBC driver into the `lib/ext` directory of your JRE. That way the PostgreSQL driver would be available in the system classpath also to applications started with `java -jar`.

If you don't want to modify your global JRE settings, you could also explicitly invoke the jackrabbit-standalone Main class with normal classpath settings, like this:

```
java -cp jackrabbit-standalone.jar:postgresql.jar \
    org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main -c ./repository.xml -p 8081 -d
```

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Can you send me the full stack trace of the NPE?

Comment: Yeah it is... not clear why, but today it's working fine.... I don't like that, because, I need to know the reason for which yesterday it didn't works! But, thanks for the help :)

Comment: The jars must be separated with a ";": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html